# Azure Data Factory from On-Premises PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to create a Linked Service connection in ADF from an on-premises PostgreSQL to Azure DW.  I've selected the PostgreSQL connection type, but am unable to establish an ODBC connection -

> "Connection refused.  Cannot connect to host"

which I think is expected considering the PostgreSQL server is on a different cloud network.

What steps do I need to take in order to create a connection between the two?  Can I create ADF Pipelines directly thereafter, or do I need to create an SSIS Runtime and work with SSIS packages only?

Comment: If you think my answer helps you,could you mark it for answer?Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to transfer data from on-premises PostgreSQL to Azure DW, i think you need to [create and configure a self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime).As the statements you could find in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#self-hosted-integration-runtime):

> A self-hosted IR is capable of running copy activity between a cloud
>   data stores and a data store in private network.

Please follow the steps to create Self-hosted IR:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime#install-and-register-self-hosted-ir-from-the-download-center

BTW,according to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats),PostgreSQL only supports source link,not for sink, which is suitable for you.